# vlc pays video created with libavcodec at wrong frame rate

Tags: h.264, vlc, libavcodec

As a test i'd like to create a video that has a framerate of 1 fps. When I create it like this vlc still plays it at 25 fps. does anybody have an idea?

```
AVFormatContext* formatContext;
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&formatContext, NULL, NULL, "test.h264");
AVOutputFormat* outputFormat = formatContext->oformat;

AVStream* videoStream = av_new_stream(formatContext, 0);
AVCodecContext* ctx  = videoStream->codec;

ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;  
ctx->codec_id = CODEC_ID_H264;    

ctx->bit_rate = 500*1000;
ctx->bit_rate_tolerance = 0;
ctx->width = w;
ctx->height = h;
ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
ctx->time_base.den = 1;//25;
ctx->time_base.num = 1;
```

Comment: what does ffmpeg -i show the framerate for the file to be? how about vlc?

Answer (score 2):

this is an old question but I hope it help others with the same problem

`AVStream` has an explicit `time_base` which is set by muxer according to container.
as stated in `AVStream.time_base` comment :

> The muxer *MAY* use the user-provided value of
>   `AVCodecContext.time_base` as a hint.

you need to use `av_rescale_q()` to set your *RAW FRAME* pts to a correct value :

```
/* AVFrame* */ raw_frame->pts = av_rescale_q(my_pts, ctx->time_base, videoStream->time_base);
.
.
.
/* AVPacket pkt; */
avcodec_encode_video2(ctx, pkt, &got_packet);
.
.
.
av_write_frame(formatContext, &pkt);
```